# How can I give only specific AWS "iam : putUserPolicy" permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Use case: In our application we need to give `iam : putUserPolicy` permissions to IAM entities. That is trivial. We can assign the policy mentioned below to the IAM entity to which we want to give `iam : putUserPolicy` permission

```js
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "iam : putUserPolicy"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Let's say we have another requirement and assign `putUserPolicy` to IAM user U1. This means that now U1 can assign ANY policy to ANY IAM user. The second "ANY" can be avoided by changing `"Resource":"*"` to `"Resource":"user-arn"`, but how do we deal with the first ANY?
Is there a way to give `"iam : putUserPolicy"` permission such that putting only "`iam : CreateUser"` permission is allowed? Or perhaps only `"iam : CreateUser"` is blocked and putting rest all policies is allowed?

I went through the AWS documentation and I found [conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) kind of helpful but I could not find any IAM service-specific keys and values though I did find some for [EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html) and [SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/UsingIAMwithSNS.html#d0e2187).

As an example we can assign the following policy:

```js
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource":"*",
      "Condition":{"StringNotEquals":["s3:prefix":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/home/"]}
      }
   ]
}
```

which gives permissions to all other S3 folders and buckets except the home folder in a particular bucket.

Can we do something like this?

```js
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":["iam:PutUserPolicy"],
      "Resource":"*",
      "Condition":{"StringNotEquals":["iam:policy-contains":"iam:CreateUser"]}
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has just introduced [Managed Policies for AWS Identity & Access Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-policies-for-aws-identity-access-management/), which provide a fresh approach to sharing and maintaining IAM policies across IAM entities, notably also including *Delegating permissions management*, see [Controlling Access to Managed Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies-managed-controlling-access.html):

> Managed policies give you precise control over how your users can manage policies and manage permissions for others. **You can separately control who can create, update, and delete policies, and who can attach and detach policies to and from principal entities** (users, groups, and roles). **You can also control which policies a user can attach or detach**, and to and from which entities. *[emphasis mine]*
>
> A typical scenario is that you give permissions to an account administrator to create, update, and delete policies. Then, you give permissions to a team leader or other limited administrator to attach and detach these policies [...].

Section [Controlling Permissions for Attaching and Detaching Managed Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies-managed-controlling-access.html#policies-controlling-access-attach-detach) provides an *Example policy that allows attaching only specific managed policies to only specific groups or roles*, which conceptually allows you to achieve what you are looking for:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
      "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:group/TEAM-A/*",
      "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:role/TEAM-A/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {"ArnLike": 
      {"iam:PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:policy/TEAM-A/*"}
    }
  }
}
```